# deserialization of java object message read through subscriber

Tags: java, jmeter, deserialization, ibm-mq

My application reads an XML request from WebSphere MQ and responds with single or multiple java object(s). While i can use JMS point-to-point sampler to post the XML request and subscriber sampler to catch the java object posted back by my application. Now i want the deserialization of the java objects to be able to assert the same. I have the required jar(s) that can help me in deserialization but i am not aware as to how i can perform this in jmeter. Can someone please provider directions as to how i can proceed?

Comment: Hi, could you please narrow down the problem you're seeing, include what you've tried and any steps to reproduce the error if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have all the necessary dependencies in your JMeter's /lib folder.

You can then just add a JSR-223 sampler/post-processor that executes the Java code that you want using those dependencies. You can choose any of the scripting languages there, but be aware of the performance problems that some of them have (BeanShell caused GC lag for me).

Answer (score 0):

Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the JMS P2P Sampler and put the deserializing code into it. When you convert binary response to String you will be able to assign the value to a JMeter Variable as:

```
vars.put("variableName", variableValue);
```

and use it in Assertion (JMeter Assertions can target JMeter Variables).

It is recommended to use [Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) as JSR223 element language as JavaScript, Beanshell, etc. interpreters have some performance issues, besides they're quite out of date and Groovy scripts can be compiled into bytecode (assuming test element being properly configured) providing maximum performance.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for instructions on how to setup groovy scripting engine support, best practices in regards to caching/using variables/etc. and some form of different scripting engines benchmark.